# Why do non-elementary limit groups over hyperbolic groups contain a non-abelian free subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

I found the above statement in the following article on page 8:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10278.pdf

I looked at some sources and did not find an answer and I also was not able to prove it by myself.

Does anybody have an idea?

If you have an answer it would be great if you could give me a reference for the proof or a similar statement because I need this for my master thesis.

Edit: My tutor said that it would be a possibility to construct an epimorphism from the limit group to a non-abelian free group. To "get back" from the free group to the limit group should be easy then, she said. But I dont know how to construct such an epimorphism.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you said which sources you had looked in, rather than you just stated that you "looked at some sources". I presume this is a factor in Shaun's comment and the 4 close votes - certainly it might have meant I or someone else could have helped you more quickly :-). The question is generally fine otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I will give more information to my problems in the future. Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: Your tutor's idea does not work. Every subgroup of a hyperbolic group $\Gamma$ is a $\Gamma$-limit group. As these can be two-generated but non-free, they do not in general surject onto $F_2$.

Instead, we should use the characterisation Proposition 1.18 in Sela's paper *Diophantine geometry over groups. VII. The elementary theory of a hyperbolic group,* Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. (3) 99 (2009), no. 1, 217–273.

> Let $\Gamma$ be a non-elementary torsion-free hyperbolic group. A finitely generated group $G$ is called $\omega$-residually $\Gamma$ if for any finite set of elements $\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}\in G$, there exists a homomorphism $h:G\to \Gamma$ that maps these elements into distinct elements in $\Gamma$.
>
> **Proposition 1.18.** Let $\Gamma$ be a non-elementary torsion-free hyperbolic group. A finitely generated group $G$ is $\omega$-residually $\Gamma$ if and only if it is a $\Gamma$-limit group.

This mirrors the situation for the classical limit groups, as fully residually free groups.

---

We will use this result combined with the following two standard results:

**Theorem (Gromov).** Let $\Gamma$ be a torsion-free hyperbolic group. For any two non-commuting elements $x, y\in\Gamma$ there exists an integer $n>0$ such that $\langle x^n, y^n\rangle$ is a non-abelian free group.

**Lemma.** Let $\phi:A\to B$ be a homomorphism. If the image $\phi(A)$ contains a non-abelian free subgroup, then $A$ contains a non-abelian free subgroup.

I'll now prove the result assuming everything is torsion-free. I'll leave you to complete the "with torsion" case.

**Theorem.**
Let $\Gamma$ be a torsion-free hyperbolic group, and let $G$ be a non-cyclic torsion-free $\Gamma$-limit group.
Then $G$ contains a non-abelian free subgroup.

*Proof.*
As $G$ is non-cyclic and torsion-free, there exists a pair of elements $a, b\in G$ such that $[a, b]=1$. By taking the set $\{a, b, [a, b], 1\}$ in Sela's Proposition 1.18, there exists a homomorphism $h: G\to\Gamma$ such that $h(a)\neq1$, $h(b)\neq1$ and $h([a, b])\neq1$. In particular, the elements $x=h(a)$ and $y=h(b)$ do not commute in $\Gamma$. By the above theorem, it follows that there exists some $n>0$ such that $\langle x^n, y^n\rangle$ is a non-abelian free group. In particular, $h(G)$ contains a non-abelian free subgroup. By the lemma, $G$ itself contains a non-abelian free subgroup as required. QED